# Check if an array contains duplicates

Tags: algorithms, computational-complexity

Check if in array contains duplicates in $O(1)$ space complexity and $ O(n)$ time complexity.

Examples:

```
Input: [1,2,3,1]
Output: true

Input: [1,2,3,4]
Output: false
```

Pretty straight forward question if space complexity can be more than $O(1)$.

How to do this in $O(1)$ space complexity and $O(n)$ time complexity. Bonus points for improving time complexity.

EDIT: Please don't use lookup tables like: `boolean[INT_MAX]` etc. I am looking for some sort of maths function which behaves in a certain way if input is repeated twice.

EDIT2: From comments below, I don't know if it can be done in the above constraints. I have this hunch that there may be a function which takes O(1) time and it's values changes in a certain way if input is repeated.
Assume that array is positive integers only.

Comment: are there some restrictions on the elements of the array. Are they integers only? Are they positive integer smaller then the length of the array?

Comment: @dingy Welcome to MSE. Please tell us where this problem comes from & why you think there's a solution fitting within your constraints of using $O(1)$ space and $O(n)$ time. Unless there are some quite strong restrictions on the elements of the array, as miracle173 has asked about, I don't see how there can be a solution.

Comment: miracle173@ Yes, array is integer only. Ideally I'd like the solution to work for all possible values but if you have a solution that works under certain conditions I'd like to know that too.

Comment: John Omielan@ This is general SDE interview question. I don't know if it can be done in the constraints I want to do it in. I have this hunch that there may be a function which takes O(1) time and it's values changes in a certain way if input is repeated.

Comment: @dingy Thanks for the additional info. I have quite a few things to say, with it being too long for comments, so I've stated them in an answer. FYI, please put the '@' in front a name if you wish the person, such as myself, to be notified that you've responded.

Comment: Maybe relevant:https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-duplicates-constant-array-elements-0-n-1-o1-space/

Comment: @NoChance That algorithm looks interesting. However, it imposes a fairly strict restriction on the size of the elements. Also, the code they've provided will not always work properly. For example, if the first element of the array has a value of $0$, then both loops will be immediately bypassed and $0$ is returned as a duplicate. There are other problems with it, e.g., it always assumes there's a duplicate returns "slow" at the end. As for the basic algorithm itself, I haven't thought about it to see if it will always normally work if implemented properly.

Comment: @JohnOmielan, It nice that you have been able to spot the weakness so fast!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note your question is basically the same as the StackOverflow one at [Find duplicates in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7055508/find-duplicates-in-an-array). You may be especially interested in the answer by [amit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/572670/amit) (description says he's a software engineer at Google), who says

> If there is no additional information, this question seems to be unsolveable, as this is the [Element Distinctness Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Element_distinctness_problem), which is unsolveable with the restrictions you provided, in the required time.

It also later says

> the idea is if we model our problem as an Algebraic Computation Tree (which is a fair assumption when no hashing is allowed, and constant space at out disposal), then, Ben Or proved in his article [Lower Bounds For Algebraic Computation Trees (1983)](https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=808735) (published in prestiged ACM), that element distinctness is `Omega(nlogn)` problem under this model. Lubiw showed that the same conclusion also applies when limiting ourselves to integers in 1991: [A Lower Bound for the Integer Element Distinctness Problem](https://www.ic.unicamp.br/~rezende/ensino/mo619/Lubiw,ALowerBoundForIntegerElementDistinctness.pdf), but these articles conclude that **under the algebraic tree computation model - Integer Distinctness Problem is Omega(nlogn) Problem**.

When I first read your problem, I recalled even the best general-purpose sorting algorithms require $O(n\log n)$ time, so I assumed something similar would also be required here, with this helping to confirm my suspicion.

The rest of the answers there provide other possibly useful information for you, including where your requirements may hold in some very special cases.

There is not much more that I have to add to what is in that link. However, for whatever it's worth, here is other options I considered. One of them was that if you only allow a fairly limited set of positive integers, you can assign each positive integer to its corresponding prime index value (e.g., $1$ goes to $2$, $2$ goes to $3$, $3$ goes to $5$, $4$ goes to $7$, etc.). Then you keep a running product of the primes, starting at $1$. For each array value, you check if the corresponding prime divides the current product. If so, you have a duplicate & stop. Otherwise, you multiply the product by the corresponding prime & go to the next value. However, this can quickly bypass any integer size limits. Also, with some sort of unlimited integer size type handling, it generally will require more memory storage than just using bits, or even bytes, in an array to store whether or not a value is used.

Another option I considered is to do a type of hashing by choosing a fairly large integer $k \gt 1$, and then get the dividend & remainder for each array value. It'll keep track of the minimum & maximum dividends encountered for each possible remainder. Of course, the same value is already there when checking, they are duplicates, so the algorithm is then finished. Otherwise, it goes through the array again, checking for the next values larger than the previous minimum & smaller than the maximum. However, this may require going through the array many times, especially in worse case scenarios where the values mostly (or even all) have the same remainder.

As for your comment that this is a "general SDE interview question", my suspicion is they're likely not be looking for a specific solution. Instead, they're possibly checking what you know about this problem, as well as what sorts of things you may suggest in terms of solving it, including which restrictions you may suggest so it can be solved as requested. During my over 30 years of computer programming, I've encountered many problems which cannot reasonably be solved as well as I would like. Instead, I've needed to compromise & just do the best I can. This was especially the case when I began programming in the late 1970's and during the 1980's when computers were much less powerful than they are now.

Comment: Under certain conditions, a radix sort can sort faster then $n\log(n)$.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort

Comment: @martycohen Yes, a radix sort (as well as other special types of sorts) can be faster under certain particular conditions, but I was referring to sorting in general.

Comment: @JohnOmielan Thanks trying to solve the problem. Since the problem itself is unsolvable, I'll accept this as answer to my question. Appreciate your time!

Comment: @dingy You are welcome. The problem, as stated, might be "unsolvable", but don't forget it's a theoretical statement. In many real-life situations, there are often some sort of restrictions that will allow you to implement something which is close to, or even matches, what you're asking about. Also, with computers being so fast now, and generally getting faster, the issues of what the order of space & time required often becomes less of an issue than other ones like amount of code required, how flexible it is, ease of maintenance, etc.